# I have created a query but it is not working

Tags: sql

```
WITH rows AS
(
    SELECT   
        *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dtDeliveryDate) AS rn
    FROM    
        TCheckRecipient
)
SELECT 
    AVG(avarage) 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         TCheck.iCheckId, 
         AVG(DATEDIFF(minute, mc.dtDeliveryDate, mp.dtDeliveryDate)) AS average
     FROM    
         rows mc
     LEFT JOIN
         TCheck ON TCheck.iCheckId = mc.iCheckId
     JOIN    
         rows mp ON mc.rn = mp.rn - 1
     GROUP BY 
         TCheck.iCheckId)
```

Comment: Posting some query without any source data and desired output and declaring "it is not working" is not very helpful. Noone here except you knows how this query supposed to work, what result should it produce and what is actually producing.

Comment: Please: 1. Elaborate the *enigmatic* is not working (doesn't compile, returns unexpected data etc., provide expected behaviour as well) and 2. *format out* the query

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: And what is the error you get?

Comment: You have typo for the column average `AVG (avarage)`

Comment: When writing "bigger" queries, start with a small query, verify it's result. Then step by step add functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You have Typo error in `AVG(avarage)` , it should be ***average***.

And also, remember to assign alias on your subquery.

```
WITH rows AS
(
    SELECT   
        *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dtDeliveryDate) AS rn
    FROM    
        TCheckRecipient
)
SELECT 
    AVG(avarage) 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         TCheck.iCheckId, 
         AVG(DATEDIFF(minute, mc.dtDeliveryDate, mp.dtDeliveryDate)) AS average
     FROM    
         rows mc
     LEFT JOIN
         TCheck ON TCheck.iCheckId = mc.iCheckId
     JOIN    
         rows mp ON mc.rn = mp.rn - 1
     GROUP BY 
         TCheck.iCheckId) as A
```